# How to get constant GPS location

Tags: android, android-location

I have following code:

```
LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
```

and `MyLocationListener` class:

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc){
        loc.getLatitude();
        loc.getLongitude();
        tv_GPSlat.setText("Latitude: " + loc.getLatitude());
        tv_GPSlon.setText("Longitude: " + loc.getLongitude());
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"GPS is not working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"GPS is working",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
        }
    }
```

I would like to save current longitude and latitude to my `TextView`s (`tv_GPSlat`, `tv_GPSlon`) but the location values are not constant (they are changing all the time). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

GPS isn't exact-  even if you don't move it will bounce around a bit.  Just put up the first location you get, and ignore future updates unless they move by more than a certain amount.  That's the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Use Location.distanceTo() to compare the new result being sent to you with the previous one.  If the distance is less than whatever threshold you want, ignore the update.

Comment: I would like to save first showed location (latitude and longitude) as soon as possible to variables, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the location and once you get it (i.e. your handler method is invoked) you have to unregister the handler in order to stop receiving the updates. Simply add this line at the end of your handler method `onLocationChanged()` in `MyLocationListener`:

```
LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
mlocManager.removeUpdates(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a data member to your location listener, and keep the previous location in it:

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public Location mSavedLocation;

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        // If we don't have saved location, or the distance between
        // the saved location and the new location is bigger than
        // 5 meters (~15ft) save the new location
        if ((mSavedLocation == null) ||
            (loc.distanceTo(mSavedLocation) > 5)) {
            mSavedLocation = loc;
        }
        // Update the screen with the current saved location
        tv_GPSlat.setText("Latitude: " + mSavedLocation.getLatitude());
        tv_GPSlon.setText("Longitude: " + mSavedLocation.getLongitude());
    }

    // ... no changes to the rest of the class
}
```

Now the rest of your code can also get the latest saved location using:

```
mlocListener.mSavedLocation
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why no one mentioned this. May be I a missing something. The call you have made has 0,0. It should have milliseconds, distanceinmeters. This way location change is only called when a particular distance is traveled OR after a time out. I am using both GPS and NETWORK providers to not be dependent on either too (sometimes GPS is not reliable).

```
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, God.KM20TIME,
            God.KM20DISTANCE, (LocationListener) updates);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, God.KM20TIME,
            God.KM20DISTANCE, (LocationListener) updates);
```